# silent installion command for installing office 2007 in MDT 2010 deployment

Tags: mdt-2010

Can any body help me out in providing some silent installation commands for installing office 2007 for MDT 2010 Deplyoment

Answer (score 1):

Create/edit the config.xml (via Deployment Workbench -> application properties -> office products tab), while specifying "Display level: None" for a silent/unattended installation.  *[source](http://blog.augustoalvarez.com.ar/2009/01/31/microsoft-deployment-toolkit-2010-beta-1-using-mdt-to-prepare-install-and-capture-customized-windows-7-images-part-ii/)*